# setBackgroundImage forBarMetrics image size?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I am fairly new in iOS programming and I am creating my first app.
I have been trying to use the following code to change the navigation bar background image (this is using the new iOS 5 method):

```
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"gradientBackgroundPlain.png"] forBarMetrics: UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

It works fine, but my image is 640 x 88 and it looks too big for the bar. It's like the system doesn't want to scale it, or do I need to do it manually? If I scale the image and create a smaller one it looks pixelated in the retina display.

Any thoughts on this?

Any help or response will be appreciated.

Thanks,

Jorge.-

Comment: Have you tried re-sizing the image to your liking? You may have to go into your photo-editing program and manually alter the dimensions of your image.

Comment: Resizing the image worked but the image looked pixelated. Mark's suggestion works well, you need to keep two versions of the image. Thanks

Comment: Could you solve your problem? I used @MarkGranoff answer and it worked fine, so maybe you can mark it as an answer to mark this question as answer.

Answer (score 18):

Your image gradientBackgroundPlain.png should be 320x44, and create a second image named gradientBackgroundPlain@2x.png with a size of 640x88. Include the @2x image in your bundle, but continue to specify gradientBackgroundPlain.png for the name of the image. The platform automatically chooses the correct size image for use depending on whether there is a retina display present or not.