# setBackgroundImage forBarMetrics + scaleToFill?

Tags: ios5, uinavigationbar, uitoolbar

Since iOS5 you should set the backgroundimage of tool- or navigationbars via setBackgroundImage forBarMetrics.

In iOS4 I use:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (CustomImage)
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed: @"NavigationBar.png"];
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}
@end
```

In iOS4 the image "scales to fill" in iOS5 the image is repeated if it's to small. Is there a way to set the behaviour to "scaleToFill" when you use setBackgroundImage forBarMetrics?

Thx!

Comment: You can reference this link:
[setbackgroundimage-forbarmetrics-image-size][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520764/setbackgroundimage-forbarmetrics-image-size