# performance / lag when overriding UINavigationBar Background Image

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar

I have implemented the following code to customize the look of my navigation bars. It works, except that I have an intermittent 1/2 second delay when navigating between two UI screens (from a fullscreen to a modal FormSheet)

```
UIImage *navBarImg = [UIImage imageNamed:@"barColor.png"];
[[UINavigationBar appearance] setBackgroundImage:navBarImg forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

Notes: the image is 8x8 single color .png
the delay happens about 25% of the time when navigating into the second screen. It's about 1/2 second and is very noticeable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After digging around some more I realized the problem is the 8x8 image size - the image is a single color as that is the effect I want . I found [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7520764/setbackgroundimage-forbarmetrics-image-size) re the correct image size.

I changed my image to a 320x44 and it now works with no delay. I didn't do the double resolution (as I don't need it for a single color image) and it didn't seam to have a problem with that. I guess it do something slow to scale up an 8x8 image